# Free function doesn't free in c

Tags: c

Everything in my code works properly except that the `freeFunc` function is stopping the run and I don't know why.

```
void orderTheFiles(char* path)
{
    int i = 0;
    DIR * dir = opendir(path);
    DIR * exampleDir = opendir(path);
    int length = checkHowMuchFiles(exampleDir);
    if (length != EXIT)
    {
        char** arr = (char**)calloc(length,sizeof(char*));
        dynamicFunc(arr, length);
        openDirectory(dir, arr);
        freeFunc(arr, length);
    }

}
```

The `checkHowMuchFiles` function is doesn't really matter as well but it  works.

Here's dynamicFunc:

```
void dynamicFunc(char** arr, int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = calloc(MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING,sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

I tried to open the directory with this function and put the whole names of files inside the dynamic array, and realloc the array by the strings length:

```
int openDirectory(DIR * dir, char** arr)
{
    int flag = 0;
    int i = 0;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir== NULL))
    {
        printf("Sorry can't open the directory\n");
        flag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (i < NUMBER_OF_GRABADGE_FILES)
        {
            readdir(dir); //This line deletes our garbage files like '.' and '..' (maybe it's just on my computer)
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            arr[i] = realloc(arr[i], (sizeof(char)*ent->d_namlen) + 1);
            strncpy(arr[i], ent->d_name, MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING);
            printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
            i++;
        }

    }
    closedir(dir);
    return flag;
}
```

The free function:

```
void freeFunc(char** arr, int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < length; i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

**note: I used dirent.h library**

Comment: Where is the code of `freeFunction`?

Comment: How are we expected to help you debug the `freeFunc()` if you don't show us the code in it?

Comment: `strncpy(arr[i], ent->d_name, MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING);` : `MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING` looks bad.

Comment: You are leaking memory like the proverbial sieve.  Your `dynamicFunc()` allocates memory for the pointers in `arr` to point at.  Your `openDirectory()` then overwrites the allocations, leaking what was previously allocated.  Are you on a system where you can use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  If so, use it.  Also, it isn't safe, in general, to assume that the directory only contains the files that the `checkHowMuchFiles()` function counts; new files could have been added since that ran.  Make sure you don't overflow the bounds of your allocated array! (Pass length to function; check it.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: wassup with the `strncpy()`?  The only possible problem is it might not null terminate the name, but it depends on the value of MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING (which might be better termed MAX_LENGTH_OF_PATH_COMPONENT).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Because Do it after `arr[i] = realloc(arr[i], (sizeof(char)*ent->d_namlen) + 1);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Oh, yes.  There's work needed there anyway since the allocation there overwrites and leaks the previous allocation.  Maybe you could be a little more explicit in your help next time.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug such issues. Don't forget to compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I misread the code; there isn't a memory leak, but there was the trouble that [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283994/free-function-doesnt-free-in-c#comment62093255_37283994).

Here's my sanitized, completed, tested, [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)-clean code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING = 256 };

static int checkHowManyFiles(const char *path)
{
    assert(path != 0);
    return 100;
}

static void oom(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void dynamicFunc(char** arr, int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < length; i++)
    {
        if ((arr[i] = calloc(MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING,sizeof(char))) == 0)
            oom();
    }
}

enum { NUMBER_OF_GRABADGE_FILES = 2 };

static int openDirectory(DIR * dir, char** arr, int num_files)
{
    int flag = 0;
    int i = 0;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir== NULL))
    {
        printf("Sorry can't open the directory\n");
        flag = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Skip . and .. */
        for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_GRABADGE_FILES; i++)
        {
            if (readdir(dir) == 0)
                break;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < num_files && (ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL; i++)
        {
            /* d_namlen is not mandated by POSIX (only d_name, d_ino are) */
            size_t namlen = strlen(ent->d_name) + 1;
            arr[i] = realloc(arr[i], namlen);
            if (arr[i] == 0)
                oom();
            strncpy(arr[i], ent->d_name, namlen);
            printf("%d [%s]\n", i, arr[i]);
        }
        flag = i;
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return flag;
}

static void freeFunc(char** arr, int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < length; i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}

static void orderTheFiles(char* path)
{
    DIR * dir = opendir(path);
    int length = checkHowManyFiles(path);
    printf("Will assume there are no more than %d files\n", length);
    if (length > 0)
    {
        char** arr = (char**)calloc(length,sizeof(char*));
        dynamicFunc(arr, length);
        int n = openDirectory(dir, arr, length);
        printf("Actually got %d files\n", n);
        freeFunc(arr, length);
    }
    else
        closedir(dir);
}

int main(void)
{
    orderTheFiles(".");
    return 0;
}
```

Note the revised interface to `checkHowManyFiles()` — which is renamed too — and the trivial implementation used.  There are over 100 files in one of the directories where I tested the code, and just 5 in another.

```
$ ../di19
==3546== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3546== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3546== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3546== Command: ../di19
==3546== 
Will assume there are no more than 100 files
0 [aes]
1 [aes.c]
2 [aes.dSYM]
3 [aes.h]
4 [makefile]
Actually got 5 files
==3546== 
==3546== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3546==     in use at exit: 26,329 bytes in 187 blocks
==3546==   total heap usage: 380 allocs, 193 frees, 63,291 bytes allocated
==3546== 
==3546== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3546==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3546==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3546==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3546==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3546==         suppressed: 26,329 bytes in 187 blocks
==3546== 
==3546== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3546== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

The code now makes sure it doesn't go stepping out of bounds.  Since POSIX only mandates `d_name` and `d_ino` in the `struct dirent` structure, I used `strlen(ent->d_name)` to determine name length.  You can decide for yourself whether that level of portability is important to you — most systems probably do provide `d_namlen`.  Note that the `openDirectory()` function now reports how many files it put into the array, and it is told how much space it has available to work in.

Pre-allocating the strings is actually mostly wasted effort.  Were it my code, I'd simply use `calloc()` for the array of (nulled) pointers, and then use `strdup()` to copy the names.  And I'd probably grow the array of pointers dynamically as needed.